# Increasing the inactivity timer Flask app

Tags: flask, development-environment, user-inactivity

I am new to development an making an app with Python Flask I want to increase the inactivity timer of my application.Currently I have tried the below mentioned solution but apparently it doesn't work.

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "JWT SECRET"
app.config['JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA'] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
app.config['JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA'] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

Comment: Where have you found the configuration option names? They do not appear in the documentation!

Comment: @rfkortekaas I saw that while researching on Google somewhere

Answer (score 3):

If you look into the [configuration documentation](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html) of JWT you can find the correct configuration options you require. They both need to be changed:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "JWT SECRET"
app.config['JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES'] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
app.config['JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES'] = datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
jwt = JWTManager(app)
```

Normally `JWT_ACCESS_TOKEN_EXPIRES` defaults to 15 minutes and `JWT_REFRESH_TOKEN_EXPIRES` defaults to 30 days.

Comment: I had the exact same problem and this answer solved it